# how to create a gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone. what i need is i have to create a gallery of images and that gallery consist only single row with group of images from the local folder in the project.And the images are shown as slide show. like for `example 0,1,2,3,4,5 are images` then they can appear like `0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,.....`. how can i done is there any predefined applications like this or examples are there pls post link or code. thank u  in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the UIScrolleView class. It should help you to do your gallery ;-)
And add in the scrollView UIImageView to show images.

If you are searching for codes, take a look at http://github.com/facebook/three20 which (If i remember correctly), implements something like that.

Good Luck !